# Add a Cassandra OSS 4.0 RC1 node into a cluster with DSE 6.0.14 nodes

Tags: cassandra

Every nodes of the cluster are in Version DSE 6.0.14, they set in ssl mode (listen on port 7001).
We're trying to add a node in version open Sources 4.0 RC1.
We force the port communication on this node:
storage_port: 7001
else the node try to communicate on the 7000 port that is closed.

We encountered the following error, when I try to start the service of the new node :

```
INFO  [main] 2021-05-10 16:22:00,985 StorageService.java:528 - Gathering node replacement information for /10.135.66.204:7001
DEBUG [main] 2021-05-10 16:22:00,986 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:112 - Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
DEBUG [main] 2021-05-10 16:22:00,996 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:112 - Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2021-05-10 16:22:01,138 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:281 - peer /10.137.65.201:54916 only supports messaging versions lower (2) than this node supports (10)
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-05-10 16:22:01,237 NoSpamLogger.java:98 - /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:7001->/xx.xxx.xx.xxx:7001-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null

[...]

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2021-05-10 16:22:02,398 TokenMetadata.java:525 - Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2021-05-10 16:22:09,467 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:360 - Failed to properly handshake with peer /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:54922. Closing the channel.
java.lang.AssertionError: null
[...]
```

I don't know if the error come from a mistake in the config of the node oss 4.0 or if there is an incompatibility between the new node version and the version of the existing node in the cluster.

Comment: tldr - you can't do that.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks a lot for your response, can you please why i can not do that? Is it an incompatibility version ?

Comment: basically - yes, there are differences between these versions - you can see from the message `only supports messaging versions lower (2) than this node supports (10)`

Comment: It does work with DSE 6 and OSS 3.11, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220374/migration-path-from-datastax-6-0-to-cassandra-3